# Number of string value occurrences for distinct another column value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model Counter which returns the following records:

```
name.....flowers.....counter  
vino.....rose.........1
vino.....lily.........1 
gaya.....rose.........1 
rosi.....lily.........1 
vino.....lily.........1 
rosi.....rose.........1 
rosi.....rose.........1
```

I want to display in the table like:

```
name | Rose | Lily |
---------------------
Vino |  1   | 2    |
---------------------
Gaya |  1   | 0    |
---------------------
Rosi |  2   | 1    |
```

I want to display the count of flowers for each distinct name. I have tried the following and wondering how can I do it elegantly?

```
def counter_results
  @counter_results= {}
  Counter.each do |name|
    rose = Counter.where(flower: 'rose').count
    lily= Counter.where(flower: 'lily').count
    @counter_results['name'] = name
    @counter_results['rose_count'] = rose
    @counter_results['lily_count'] = lily
  end
  return @counter_results
end
```

which I don't get the hash values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you slightly different output, but I think it is probably closer to what you want than what you showed.

You can use the query:

```
Counter.group([:name, :flowers]).sum(:counter)
```

To get a result set that looks like:

```
{ ["vino", "rose"] => 1, ["vino", "lily"] => 2, ["gaya", "rose"] => 1, ["gaya", "lily"] => 0, ... }
```

And you can do something like this to generate your hash:

```
def counter_results
  @counter_results = {}
  Counter.group([:name, :flowers]).sum(:counter).each do |k, v|
    @counter_results[k.join("_")] = v
  end
  @counter_results
end
```

The resulting hash would look like this:

```
{
  "vino_rose" => 1,
  "vino_lily" => 2,
  "gaya_rose" => 1,
  "gaya_lily" => 0,
  ...
}
```

Somebody else may have a better way to do it, but seems like that should get you pretty close.

Comment: Thanks @dinjas. Is it possible that we can get the same type results without using the column counter?

Comment: @Vinay Yea, you should be able to do `Counter.group([:name, :flowers]).count`

Comment: Thank you very much @dinjas. That's worked. Can you advise that using REGEX is a good way to split the name from vino_rose to Vino?

Comment: @Vinay, it depends on what you're doing with it. If you just need to split it, you can do `name = "vino_rose".split("_").first; flower = "vino_rose".split("_").last` You can use a regex to see if the string contains a substring like `"vino_rose" =~ /vino/` (will return the index in the string the match occurs at, `0` in this case, or `nil` if no match). You can also do `"vino_rose".include?("vino")` which will return `true` or `false`

Comment: Thank you very much and really appreciate your explanations helps me to understand clearly. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful!

Comment: One more question @dinjas Is it possible to put `0` if the `name` does not have `flowers`? E.g., `Name-Gaya` does not have `Flower-Rose`

Comment: I'm not sure how you're accessing your data, but you should be able to convert `nil` to `0`. E.g. if your hash is `h = { "vino_rose" => 1, "vino_lily" => 2, "gaya_rose" => 1 }` and you do `h["gaya_lily"]`, you'll get `nil`, so you can do `h["gaya_lily"].to_i`, which will give you `0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97352/discussion-between-vinay-and-dinjas).

Comment: Thanks @dinjas. I am bit confused now. I want to display into the table of distinct of names and each flower count. E.g., `Vino 1 2 0` where `name, rose_count, lily_count, sunflower_count`.